# Using members of Var type

Tags: c#, var

After declaring an object of implicit type with `var` keyword, is it possible to use the members, methods or properties specific to the type that has been assigned to it by compiler in any further statements?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Aside: you don't declare an *object* using `var`; you declare a *variable*. It's a good idea to keep a very clear separation in your head between variables, objects, references etc.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, absolute - because `var` isn't actually a type. It just tells the compiler: "I'm not going to *explicitly* tell you the type - just use the compile-time type of the right-hand operand of the assignment operator to work out what type the variable is."

So for example:

```
var text = "this is a string";
Console.WriteLine(text.Length); // Uses string.Length property
```

As well as being convenient, `var` was introduced to enable *anonymous types*, where you *couldn't* declare the variable type explicitly. For example:

```
// The type involved has no name that we can refer to, so we *have* to use var.
var item = new { Name = "Jon", Hobby = "Stack Overflow" };
Console.WriteLine(item.Name); // This is still resolved at compile-time.
```

Compare this with `dynamic`, where the compiler basically defers any use of members until execution-time, to bind them based on the *execution-time* type:

```
dynamic foo = "this is a string";
Console.WriteLine(foo.Length); // Resolves to string.Length at execution time

foo = new int[10]; // This wouldn't be valid with var; an int[] isn't a string
Console.WriteLine(foo.Length); // Resolves to int[].Length at execution time

foo.ThisWillGoBang(); // Compiles, but will throw an exception
```

Comment: @MikeDebela: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824739/implicit-typing-why-just-local-variables

Answer (score 2):

If you use `var`, the you have to immediately initialize the variable. Example:

```
var a = 1;
```

This tells the compiler it's an int. But if you don't initialize, then the compiler doesn't know what type it should be using.

```
var b;
```

What type is `b`?

The same applies for members of classes.

`var` is just a convenience feature so you don't have to type in the name of the class or the fully qualified namespace.