# Why infer doesn't work on static but works on dim?

Tags: vb.net, static, option-infer

```
    Static hashTimeDifferrence As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)
```

works fine

```
    Static hashTimeDifferrence = New HashSet(Of String)
```

doesn't

```
    Dim hashTimeDifferrence2 = New HashSet(Of String)
```

works because option infer is on.

I think it should work for dim and static.

Is this a bug in vb.net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit typing; why just local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824739/implicit-typing-why-just-local-variables)

Comment: May be related but not duplicate.

Comment: It's clearly not a bug: the VB documentation states, "The data types of Static local variables cannot be inferred."  I would expect the reasoning to be identical to module-level items, since `Static` is functionally defining a module-level item but with only local scope.

Comment: Bro. VB documentation? Where?

Comment: Try pressing F1 in a VB document with a VB keyword highlighted.  I have the help docs installed locally, but it's also all available on the web.  In my local help docs, there is a "Visual Basic" node at the top level (underneath "Help Viewer Home").

Comment: Also, please tag us (using the '@" character and our user name) so that we are notified of replies, otherwise it's easy to forget to come back and look at the question and see that there's a follow-up comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fundamental reason why, it is actually just a missed edge case from when Infer was introduced. The former VB PM Anthony Green used it as a reference in how to make breaking changes: https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/312