# Is there a way to shorten field declaration in C#?

Tags: c#, new-operator

Why do I have to write:

```
public VeryLongClassNameThatHurtsMyEyes<AnotherVeryLongClassName> field = new VeryLongClassNameThatHurtsMyEyes<AnotherVeryLongClassName>();
```

Instead of:

```
public var field = new VeryLongClassNameThatHurtsMyEyes<AnotherVeryLongClassName>();
```

Is there any way to shorten this ridiculous declaration?
Why do I have to write **two** identical types in a single line?

**Upd.**
I have found that using "dynamic" keyword instead of "var" perfectly solves this problem!
Please feel free to provide any info on the perfomance (or other) issues with this solution!

Comment: Your concern is that the long type name results in a long field declaration. Aliasing the type name with a shorter one will address that aspect. See first marked duplicate. Your question is unclear, but it's possible you are also/instead asking why you can't use `var`. See second marked duplicate for that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824739/implicit-typing-why-just-local-variables is also pertinent.

Comment: if it was me, I would initialize the properties in the constructor anyways.

Comment: I have found that using "dynamic" keyword instead of "var" perfectly solves this problem! Please feel free to provide any info on the perfomance (or other) issues with this solution!

Comment: _"using "dynamic" keyword instead of "var" perfectly solves this problem!"_ -- no, it doesn't. At compile-time `dynamic` is effectively `object`, delaying all of the resolution of uses of the variable to runtime. You'll get no Intellisense on the field, no compile-time type-checking, no verification of member usages, etc. This is a _horrible_ way to deal with the issue. Frankly, you are making too much of the problem; Intellisense makes it very quick to _type_ the declaration, reading it is not any trouble at all, and if you really hate it, just use a type alias as seen in the duplicate.

Comment: Do *not* use `dynamic` to simply shorten a line of code.  Among other things you are disabling compile time type checks.  That's not the intended usage of `dynamic`.  I would strongly advise researching how `dynamic` works before using it in your code.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that for dynamic a separate runtime is required, the DLR.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type alias.  Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive). Link to alias for generic class: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#example-2)

```
using YourShortName = VeryLongClassNameThatHurtsMyEyes<AnotherVeryLongClassName>;
```

Usage

```
public YourShortName field = new YourShortName();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824739/implicit-typing-why-just-local-variables) for why you can only use `var` for local variables.

And [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamic-c-4-and-var) for an in depth look at `dynamic` and why it's not even remotely close to using `var`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is that something you can do with fields?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the OP is asking about a field, `var` wouldnt work

Comment: I am mostly asking why wouldn't it work: am I asking too much from the compiler? I just don't understand this silly boilerplate

Comment: I have found that using "dynamic" keyword instead of "var" perfectly solves this problem! Please feel free to provide any info on the perfomance (or other) issues with this solution!

Comment: @Nidere You likely want to search SO for answers on this.  But a _very_ big difference is you are disabling compile time type checks.  I would strongly advise against simply using `dynamic` to shorten a line of code.

Comment: @Nidere using `dynamic` is about the _worst_ thing you could do.

Comment: @Nidere i think you need this reinforced, you are solving a non-issue by creating a boat load more problems in the future (what will likely need refactoring out an reversed) by using dynamic, and you would likely fail any sane code review. please take peoples advice